# Building JSON in ASP, I'm not sure how to build this part in Json.net or with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json, json.net, javascriptserializer

Everyone!

I'm building JSON and I'm not sure how to build this part of the JSON.

```
'playlist': [
        {
           'file': 'bunny.mp4',
           'title': 'Big Buck Bunny Trailer',
           'provder': 'rtmp',
           'streamer': 'rtmp://rtmp.server.com/application',
           'image': 'http://thumbnails.server.com/thumbs/bunny.jpg',
           'duration': '33.03',
           'description': 'An animated short from the Blender project'
        },
        {
           'file': 'sintel.mp4',
           'title': 'Sintel',
           'streamer': 'rtmp://rtmp.server.com/application',
           'image': 'http://thumbnails.server.com/thumbs/sintel.jpg',
           'provider': 'rtmp',
           'duration': '888.06',
           'description': 'An animated short from the Blender project'
        },
        {
           'file': 'elephant.mp4a',
           'title': 'Elephant´s Dream',
           'streamer': 'rtmp://rtmp.server.com/application',
           'image': 'http://thumbnails.server.com/thumbs/elephant.jpg',
           'provider': 'rtmp',
           'duration': '653.79',
           'description': 'An animated short from the Blender project'
        }
    ]
```

I can do the playlist part, but I'm not sure about the three sub parts.

The full json would look like this

```
{
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'id': 'playerID',
    'width': '650',
    'height': '240',
    'playlist.position': 'right',
    'playlist.size': '250',
    'playlist': [
        {
           'file': 'bunny.mp4',
           'title': 'Big Buck Bunny Trailer',
           'provder': 'rtmp',
           'streamer': 'rtmp://rtmp.server.com/application',
           'image': 'http://thumbnails.server.com/thumbs/bunny.jpg',
           'duration': '33.03',
           'description': 'An animated short from the Blender project'
        },
        {
           'file': 'sintel.mp4',
           'title': 'Sintel',
           'streamer': 'rtmp://rtmp.server.com/application',
           'image': 'http://thumbnails.server.com/thumbs/sintel.jpg',
           'provider': 'rtmp',
           'duration': '888.06',
           'description': 'An animated short from the Blender project'
        },
        {
           'file': 'elephant.mp4a',
           'title': 'Elephant´s Dream',
           'streamer': 'rtmp://rtmp.server.com/application',
           'image': 'http://thumbnails.server.com/thumbs/elephant.jpg',
           'provider': 'rtmp',
           'duration': '653.79',
           'description': 'An animated short from the Blender project'
        }
    ]
  }
```

I can do everything but the items in the playlist. I was using a dictionary object before, and just called (JavaScriptSerializer) serializer.Serialize(ConfigurationDictionary) to turn it into the JSON I wanted.

Is there a way to get the result I wanted with the part within the playlist part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the 'playlist' property an array or list of Song or Track object which contain the properties listed (file, title, streamer, image, provider, duration, description)

```
Public Class Track
 Public Property file as String
 Public Property title as String 
 (etc)
End Class

Public Class Playlist
 Public Property flashplayer As String
 (etc)
 Public Property playlist As List(Of Track)
End Class
```

Then you can just use the JSON library or function.